# Vertically center issue in bootstrap 4 and laravel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm trying to vertically center my column content.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container d-flex h-100">
  <div class="row mt-5 ">
    <div class="col-sm-7 about-us">
      <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <h3 class="display-3 strong ">
          {{ __('Message From Chief ') }}
        </h3>
        <p>
          {{ __('This is a sample text') }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="{{asset('img/user.jpg') }}" class="img img-fluid" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

But when I tried the above code it is giving me a massive gap in between the heading and para.

So how can I properly align my texts vertically center and where am I doing wrong here

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and Laravel.

Comment: Btw as far as i know if you're using bootstap layout, all the content should be placed in COL's and not ROW's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `min-vh-100` in your `.container` class and add `align-content-center` in your `row` class.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container d-flex min-vh-100">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7 about-us">
      <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center align-content-center flex-column">
        <h3 class="display-3 strong ">Message From Chief</h3>
        <p>This is a sample text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="{{asset('img/user.jpg') }}" class="img img-fluid" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: tried, but now I can't seperate the para and the heading, they both display inline

Comment: hello this is how it look like currently https://prnt.sc/s374qj

Comment: there is no difference, exactly pasted your code apart from the js libraries and the css as I already have them in use

Comment: ok so add `flex-column` class in your parent .row class

Comment: like that `<div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center align-content-center flex-column">`

Comment: Yes, now it's working, please edit the answer i will accept it , thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.h-100` in your .container class , add `.h-100` in your row class and add `.my-auto` in your col class.

```
<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-sm-7 about-us my-auto">
      <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <h3 class="display-3 strong ">
          {{ __('Message From Chief ') }}
        </h3>
        <p>
          {{ __('This is a sample text') }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="{{asset('img/user.jpg') }}" class="img img-fluid" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```